# DEOptim access violation / crash

Tags: r

The following code causes an access violation in R (using RGui).  If I use RStudio, then RStudio crashes citing DEOptim.dll.  I am using DEoptim 2.1-1.  Everything works fine if I reduce the length of lower/upper.  The documentation states that as of 2.0-3 the limit on the number of parameters to optimize has been lifted (in the conversion of DEoptim to C code).  Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Advice on how to proceed?

```
library(DEoptim)
objFunc = function( x )
{
    return(mean(x))
}
lower = rep( -.1 , 400 )
upper = rep( .1 , 400 )
result = DEoptim( objFunc , lower = lower , upper = upper )

Traceback:
 1: .Call("DEoptimC", lower, upper, fn, ctrl, new.env(), PACKAGE = "DEoptim")
 2: DEoptim(objFunc, lower = lower, upper = upper)
Error in DEoptim(objFunc, lower = lower, upper = upper) : 
  caught access violation - continue with care
```

Comment: I would contact the package maintainer. A crash is a bug by definition.

Comment: does it work when you don't use RStudio? It's possible that code that crashes RStudio could be an RStudio bug, no? Or, similar, it could be a Windows bug, but it's probably RStudio or the package.

Comment: Hi Xu - It causes an access violation in R, with no crash.  If I use RStudio, then I get the crash.  So in either case something bad happens.  I updated the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ben Bolker said, a crash is a bug.  Thank you for the minimal reproducible example.  I will fix this today.

UPDATE: Patched on R-forge, revision 73.  Will push to CRAN in a couple days.

Comment: I saw that the solution was a fix to initialpop.  Is there still a limit on number of parameters?  My example uses 400, but in practice I'd like to use 550-600.  Will that be possible?

Comment: @SFun28: The initial population was being created on the stack and the size of your population was causing a stack overflow.  I moved the code to use the heap instead, so you will only run into issues if you bump up against your computer's memory limits.  For example, I was able to run your example with `lower` and `upper` each having 1,000 elements.